# Search in array and use it to save

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I've been working this week on a special project with imports. the function that i have created import a xml from diffrent sources and save this in my database.

My solution on that is:
- Save al the keys that i want from the XML and save it into my database.

But because every XML is different i want to search into my array of one of those XML and search for the key that i want to save.

The problem is now:
- I've an array of events, i want the value of the key and save it into my database.

My XML example array:

```
[
 [event] =>
           [
            [0] =>
                  [
                   [foo1] => [bar1]
                   [foo2] => [bar2]
                  ]
            [1] =>
                  [
                   [foo1] => [bar3]
                   [foo2] => [bar4]
                  ]
           ]
]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I were you, I will search the xml directly instead of building arrays. Even if your xml files are different, there's probably a way to extract what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you try **array_keys** function? It returns the keys from an array where finds the value that you indicate

look this

http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php

```
array_keys($array, "search_value");
```

Comment: Thnx a lot! Then is the question how to loop throw those events?

Comment: sorry I put the link in spanish, here is in english
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php, the function returns an array with the keys so you can use maybe a foreach cycle to get each key

Comment: array_keys() doesn't work with multidimensional array... alternative ?

Comment: you can use the function **array_column**, I have a similar case where I need to know the position of an especific element, so I take just the column where my search value is (the only change is that I use array_search instead of array_keys, this is my code --**array_search("search_value", array_column($datos, 'column_name'));**

Comment: Thnx, but on this i get an bool and not the value of the collumn

Comment: a boolean result? which function returns a boolean?

Comment: $lol = array_search("search_value", array_column($results, 'eventId')); he gives me a bool false. and i know i need to change 'search_value' but i don't know the value i only know the key

Comment: @mickmackusa can you help me with this issue ?